# TensorFlow undefined options value

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I tried to use **model.fit** in Tensorflow and add options it keeps showing me this error for **batchSize** and **epochs**, I have checked the docs and it is the same as I did so what could be the error

```
model = Sequential([
    Dense(units=16,input_shape=(1,), activation='relu'), # layer 1
    Dense(units=32, activation='relu'), # layer 2
    Dense(units=2, activation='softmax'), # layer 3 fully connected layer
])
```

[image]

```
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['aaccracy'])

model.fit(scaled_train_samples, train_labels, {
   batchSize: 4,
   epochs: 3
})
```

[image]

I tried to use it this way and it show me this error also

```
model.fit(scaled_train_samples, train_labels, batch_size=4,epochs=3)
```

[image]

**scaled_train_samples**

```
[
[0.22093023]
[0.6627907]
[0.44186047]
[0.40697674]
[0.97674419]
[0.04651163]
[0.19767442]
[0.61627907]
[0.03488372]
[0.44186047]
[0.43023256]
[0.8255814]
[0.48837209]
[0.20930233]
[0.46511628]
[0.81395349]
[0.15116279]
[0.18604651]
[0.43023256]
[0.61627907]
]
```

**train_labels**

```
[
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0

]
```

Comment: give me this : `scaled_train_samples.shape` and `train_labels.shape` ?

Comment: check my question I have updated it with the data you need @I'mahdi

Comment: I think before `model.fit()`, somewhere you assign `None` to `model`, then you can not call `None.fit()`

Comment: I have added my model setup in the question please check @I'mahdi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

scaled_train_samples = [
    [0.44186047],[0.40697674],[0.97674419],[0.04651163],[0.19767442],
    [0.61627907],[0.03488372],[0.44186047],[0.43023256],[0.8255814],
    [0.48837209],[0.20930233],[0.46511628],[0.81395349],[0.15116279],
    [0.18604651],[0.43023256],[0.61627907]]

train_labels = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]

print(np.asarray(scaled_train_samples).shape)
# (18, 1)

print(np.asarray(train_labels).shape)
# (18,)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=16,input_shape=(1,), activation='relu'), # layer 1
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=32, activation='relu'), # layer 2
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2, activation='softmax'), # layer 3 fully connected layer
])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), 
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
              metrics=['acc'])

model.fit(scaled_train_samples, train_labels, batch_size=4, epochs=3)
```

---

```
Epoch 1/3
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6921 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 2/3
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.6916 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 3/3
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 0.6914 - acc: 0.5556
```

Comment: this work, thanks  @I'mahdi
just a question what was the issue I can see you update **metrics**

Comment: @mohamednageh, we don't have `metric:aaccracy ` :(

Comment: @mohamednageh, You can use [these_metrics](https://keras.io/api/metrics/#metrics) or you can write your [own_metric](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Metric) like this `doc`

Comment: @mohamednageh, you're welcome, have good time ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `NameError: name 'batchSize' is not defined` diagnostic is pretty clear.

Without defining a pair of string constants,
you wrote

```
fit(..., ..., {
   batchSize: 4,
   epochs: 3
})
```

You meant either

(1.)

```
fit(..., ..., {
   'batchSize': 4,
   'epochs': 3
})
```

or equivalently

(2.)

```
fit(..., ..., dict(
   batchSize=4,
   epochs=3
))
```

Comment: It shows me this error when I tried both solutions you mentioned @J_H
**unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'dict'**